# Tautological vector bundle over G1(R2) isomorphic to the Möbius bundle explicitily?

Tags: vector-bundles, mobius-band

TShow that the tautological vector bundle over  G1(R2) is smoothly isomorphic to the Möbius bundle. How can I write a isomorphism explicitily?

Comment: Can you show that the two are isomorphic in some other way?

Comment: Yes, but I can´t figure out how

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I don´t know how to prove the statement  "the tautological vector bundle over G1(R2) is smoothly isomorphic to the Möbius bundle."